# I have created rest api using loopback and trying to call external api using rest connector and I want to display the result to the 1 api call

Tags: node.js, api, rest, loopbackjs

my case,I have create rest api which it should call external api and should display the response to the client using rest connector, i have added the below code in `datasources.js`

```
{"aci":{
    "name": "aci",
    "connector": "rest",
    "operations": [{
        "template": {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "http://192.168.220.1:7800/esb/esb_cbs_service/AccountInfo",
            "headers": {
                "accepts": "application/json",
                "content-type": "application/json"
            },
            "form": {
                "ACCTINFOTRNRQ": {
                    "TRNUID": "12345",
                    "ACCTINFORQ": {
                        "DTACCTUP": "20050101"
                    }
                }
            },

            "responsePath": "$.results[0].AccountInfoResponse.Item"
        },
        "functions": {
            "acif": [
                "customerId",
                "customerName"
            ]
        }
    }]

}}
```

in `model.js`

```
module.exports = function(Acim) {
    //remote method
    Acim.extcall = function(Acim, cb){
       cb(null, res);
    }
    };

    Acim.remoteMethod('extcall',{
       accepts: [{arg: 'customerId type" 'string''}]
       returns: {arg: 'customerId', type: 'type'}
       http: {path:'/getAci', verb: 'post'}
     })
```

and when I reload the project I am facing this error. Please I am stuck here, what am I doing wrong?

```
C:\Users\user\acinfo>apic loopback:refresh
```

Updating swagger and product definitions
ERROR Cannot load the LoopBack application: Cannot load the LoopBack application: Cannot create data source "aci": Cannot initialize connector "RequestBuilder": Cannot read property 'root' of undefined
Please fix the problem and run `apic loopback:refresh`

Please fix the problem and run `apic loopback:refresh`

Comment: I see an extra bracket in model.js.